# How to set MTU for autoconfigured interfaces

Tags: boot, networking, configuration, interface

I have a computer that may have multiple network devices, which are only in some cases available. Currently all network devices are configured completely automatically.

Now I need to set the MTU for all network interfaces except for lo. However I cannot figure out where I can configure this.

My `/etc/network/interface` is as follows:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I already tried adding scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d`, `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d` and `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient-exit-hooks.d`, but none of these scripts seem to get executed.

I never did anything to configure these networks, they just always worked out of the box. I do not want these networks to be configured statically, since only some of them may be present at any time, and I want to skip dhcp etc. during bootup if the network is not available.

For a while I had a configuration for some of these networks in `/etc/network/interfaces` but this greatly increased bootup time so I removed it.

Where can I set the MTU in this case?